# Atheism vs. Agnosticism - one tag will do or do we need two?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

So I accidentally created a new tag [atheism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atheism) not knowing there was already one with the name [agnosticism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agnosticism)

Do we need two tags or one? I guess the mods can link up both via a synonym.

But more importantly, does Hinduism differentiate one from the other? Don't most of us start out as agnostic ('*[unsure whether atheism or theism is more reasonable](http://atheism.about.com/od/aboutagnosticism/a/Atheist-vs-Agnostic-Difference.htm)*')?

Comment: I think the atheism tag is fine, but I don't think agnosticism would ever be a big enough category of question to warrant a tag.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, you mean keep atheism separate from the other? I've seen many people use it interchangeably.

Comment: I think we should just remove the agnostic tag from all questions, and then apply the atheism tag wherever it's relevant.

Comment: To be clear, what I'm suggesting is that for questions about atheism we should apply the atheist tag, and then for questions about agnosticism we shouldn't put any tag at all.  That's because I think the number of questions on this site that are exclusively about agnosticism are extremely small and are likely to remain small for the foreseeable future.

Comment: By the way, this is off-topic but I don't think it's necessarily true that most people start out as agnostic.  I don't think there was ever a moment in my life where I would have said "I am unsure whether atheism or theism is true."  Of course at a sufficiently young age I didn't even have the concept of gods, but from the moment I heard about them I believed in them.  At a very young age I just automatically assumed that they existed, just as I automatically assumed relatives that I had never met existed.  And then as I got older I found more conclusive reasons why Hinduism must be true.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this describes a problem that can't be reproduced that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers.